# Classify trajectory compression algorithm

Tags: trajectory, compression

I'm tryng to classify each compression algorithm based upon their features, i've thinked:

- Compression algorithm

  - Lossless algorithm

    - Batched algorithm

      - Rinex
  - Lossy algorithm

    - Batched algorithm

      - Uniform sampling
      - Douglas-Peucker
      - Bellman
    - Online algorithm

      - Opening window
    - Hybrid algorithm

      - Threshold algorithm

Do you agree with me? How can I improve this chart? The main division is among lossless and lossy or batched and online? Exist an online lossless algorithm?

Best regard